# How do I remove only the first character of a string that is not a digit? (MFC, C++)

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to remove only the first character in a string that is NOT a digit.  The first character can be anything from ‘A’ to ‘Z’ or it may be a special character like ‘&’ or ‘#’.  This legacy code is written in MFC.  I've looked at the CString class but cannot figure out how to make this work.

I have strings that may look like any of the following:
J22008943452GF or 22008943452GF or K33423333333IF or 23000526987IF or #12000895236GF.  You get the idea by now.

My dilemma is I need to remove the character in the first position of all the strings, but not the strings that starts with a digit.  For the strings that begin with a digit, I need to leave them alone.  Also, none of the other characters in the string should not be altered.  For example the ‘G’, ‘I’ or ‘F’ in the later part of the string should not be changed. The length of the string will always be 13 or 14 digits.

Here is what I have so far.

```
CString GAbsMeterCalibration::TrimMeterSNString (CString meterSN)
 {
   meterSN.MakeUpper();
   CString TrimmedMeterSNString = meterSN;
   int strlength = strlen(TrimmedMeterSNString);

    if (strlength == 13)
       {
         // Check the first character anyway, even though it’s
         //  probably okay.  If it is a digit, life’s good.
         //  Return unaltered TrimmedMeterSNString;
       }

    if (strlength == 14)) 
       {
           //Check the first character, it’s probably going
           //  to be wrong and is a character, not a digit.  

           // if I find a char in the first postion of the
           //    string, delete it and shift everything to the 
           //    left.  Make this my new TrimmedMeterSNString
           //  return altered TrimmedMeterSNString;
        }
 }
```

The string lengths are checked and validated before the calls.

From my investigations, I’ve found that MFC does not have a regular expression 
class.  Nor does it have the substring methods.

Comment: "Nor does it have the substring methods" - yes it does? [Mid, Left, Right](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa315043(v=vs.60).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
CString GAbsMeterCalibration::TrimMeterSNString (CString meterSN)
 {
   meterSN.MakeUpper();
   CString TrimmedMeterSNString = meterSN;
   int strlength = strlen(TrimmedMeterSNString);

    if (std::isdigit(TrimmedMeterSNString.GetAt(0)) )
       {
         // Check the first character anyway, even though it’s
         //  probably okay.  If it is a digit, life’s good.
         //  Return unaltered TrimmedMeterSNString;
       }
 }
```

Comment: Should that be GetAt(0) for the first character? And he should be using wide characters so regular isdigit probably isn't enough. And I think his problem was trimming the string, which you've glossed over.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want to remove the first letter if it is not a digit. So you may make this function simpler:

```
CString GAbsMeterCalibration::TrimMeterSNString(CString meterSN)
{
    meterSN.MakeUpper();

    int length = meterSN.GetLength();

    // just check the first character is always a digit else remove it
    if (length > 0 && unsigned(meterSN[0] - TCHAR('0')) > unsigned('9'))
    {
        return meterSN.Right(length - 1);
    }

    return meterSN;
}
```

I am not using function *isdigit* instead of the conditional trick with *unsigned* because CString uses TCHAR which can be either *char* or *wchar_t*.

Comment: You can use `.Mid(1)` rather than `Right` to strip the first character I think, and there's [`_istdigit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc4ksh8.aspx) that handles tchars.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is fairly straight forward:

```
CString GAbsMeterCalibration::TrimMeterSNString(CString meterSN) {
    meterSN.MakeUpper();
    return _istdigit(meterSN.GetAt(0)) ? meterSN :
                                         meterSN.Mid(1);
}
```

The implementation can be compiled for both ANSI and Unicode project settings by using [_istdigit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc4ksh8.aspx). This is required since you are using `CString`, which stores either MBCS or Unicode character strings. The desired substring is extracted using [`CStringT::Mid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4c90k3d.aspx).

(Note that `CString` is a typedef for a specific `CStringT` template instantiation, depending on your project settings.)

Answer (score 0):

```
CString test="12355adaddfca";
if((test.GetAt(0)>=48)&&(test.GetAt(0)<=57))
{
//48 and 57 are ascii values of 0&9, hence this is a digit
//do your stuff
 //CString::GetBuffer may help here??
}
else
{
//it is not a digit, do your stuff

}
```

Compare the ascii value of the first position in the string and you know if it's a digit or not..

Comment: It's not `std::string`, it's MFC's CString which usually contains wide characters. And it's the 'do your stuff' bit he's asking about.

Comment: May I suggest not ever using magic numbers in code? What's wrong with `_T('0')` and `_T('9')`, respectively? Someone will have to maintain this code, at some point. Also, `GetBuffer` is the wrong tool here.

Comment: agreed on magic numbers part...Enums would be appropriate here.

Comment: No, enums would not be appropriate, since they have the wrong data type. I provided a properly typed suggestion in my previous comment already.

Comment: wrong datatype in this case....but in general, when you use an explicit integer value to do an operation say in bitset<>, you want to flip a bit, you could do x.set(7)...But then enum would fit in here,right??

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've tried this, but, it should work.

```
CString str = _T("#12000895236GF");
//  check string to see if it starts with digit.
CString result = str.SpanIncluding(_T("0123456789"));
//  if result is empty, string does not start with a number
//  and we can remove the first character.  Otherwise, string
//  remains intact.
if (result.IsEmpty())
    str = str.Mid(1);
```

Seems a little easier than what's been proposed.

Comment: The second parameter to `Mid` is called `nCount`. You are attempting to extract more characters than are available. It's probably also easier on the maintenance developer to write succinct code. Extracting a span of characters that you're not interested in is hardly helpful. Simply implement a check for the first character being a digit if that is the check you want to perform.

Comment: @IInspectable  Thanks for that catch.  I've updated my answer.  I will, however, respectfully disagree with your opinion.  The _SpanIncluding_ is not meant to extract a string.  Rather, it's meant to tell if the first character is a digit.  Just another way, albeit, not what you'd prefer, to accomplish the task.

Comment: Got to love the mystery down vote! At least provide a reason.